# The character '\' as a string in python

Tags: python, printing, char

How do I use the character '\' as a string in python?

```
save_place = 'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop'
save_place = save_place + '\'
```

Thanks to all the helpers :)

Comment: save_place = 'C:\\Users\\Ron\\Desktop'

Comment: @Dmitry.Samborskyi not what I ment

Comment: @RonHalfon You forgot to specify what else you meant...

Comment: save_place = save_place + '\\'

Comment: @fahad It worked!! Thank you :)